# Constructional Vs Construction?

Tags: differences

Can anybody explain to me why it is not right to say constructional materials? I don't understand why construction (a noun) is more appropriate than constructional (an adjective)
Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

*Constructional materials* sounds rather ugly to my BrE ears. The first word is made up of four Latin elements and it is followed by a Latin (via Old French) word. It's just too much Latin! *Construction materials* is perfectly clear. *Governmental* is similarly abbreviated to *government* where its adjectival form might seem more correct grammatically.

Also, both *constructional* and *material(s)* end with *-al*. And each is made up of two iambs, which means they are stressed identically. So although they don't *rhyme* exactly, they certainly jangle when they're put together.

BUT there's nothing actually **wrong** with *constructional materials* and I'm not sure why you say there is. If some grammar-checker disallowed it then it must be because the word *constructional* is not much used nowadays.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=constructional%20materials%2Cconstruction%20materials&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconstructional%20materials%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconstruction%20materials%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconstructional%20materials%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconstruction%20materials%3B%2Cc0) shows the relative use of your two expressions and the [decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=constructional&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconstructional%3B%2Cc0) of *constructional*. In the UK the word seems to have peaked at the end of WWII. Perhaps military leaders use Latinate words more than the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

Using *constructional* isn't grammatically wrong. But we use nouns (called noun adjuncts) to modify other nouns in English all the time. You should not think of using a noun adjunct as less grammatical than using an adjective. For example, we say *horse racing* instead of *equine racing*, *rock wall* rather than *rocky wall*, *water tower* rather than *aquatic tower*.

There are undoubtedly general guidelines for when to use noun adjuncts and when to use adjectives that native English speakers know intuitively, but nobody teaches them, and they are probably really complicated and have numerous exceptions. This is a question that a linguist could write a long dissertation on.

For *materials*, if we're describing what the materials are used for, we generally use a noun. For example *art materials* are paint, paper, brushes, easels, etc. And *artistic materials* might be these, but they might also be materials with some inherent artistic quality to them.